# How to convert Laravel 7 error json to this new json

Tags: php, json, laravel

**Hello, I would like to know if it is possible for me to transform Laravel's error json into this new json.
I'm using Laravel 7**

```
  {
        "message": "The given data was invalid.",
        "errors": {
            "email": [
                "email is already in use"
            ],
            "username": [
                "username is already in use"
            ]
        }
    }
```

to

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": "email is already in use",
        "username": "username is already in use"
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside of your controller are you using the `Validator` facade or `$request->validate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your controller if you validate your POST request with the Validator facade you can convert the errors into a collection and map over them.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

// Faking the Request array & Commenting out to fail request
$input = [
  // 'username' => 'username',
  // 'password' => 'password',
];

$validator = Validator::make((array) $input, [
  'username' => 'required|unique|string',
  'password' => 'required|string',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  $formatted = collect($validator->errors())->map(function ($error) {
    return $error[0];
  });

  return response()->json([
      'message' => 'The given data was invalid.',
      'errors' => $formatted,
    ], 422);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose a different approach to the problem.

In you User model you could add a class method called `ValidationBook`.

```
public static function ValidationBook($except = [], $append = [])
{
    $book = ['rules' => [], 'messages' => []];
    $book['rules'] = [
        'user.email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'user.password' => 'required|min:8',
        'user.password_confirmation' => 'required|min:8|same:user.password',
    ];
    $book['messages'] = [
        'user.email.required' => 'The email is required',
        'user.email.email' => 'The email must be a valid email address.',
        'user.email.unique' => 'This email is already in use.',

        'user.password.required' => 'A password is required.',
        'user.password.min' => 'Password musst have at least 8 characters',

        'user.password_confirmation.required' => 'The password confirmation is required.',
        'user.password_confirmation.same' => 'Passwords doesn't match',
    ];
    if (!empty($except)) {
        $except = array_flip($except);
        $book['rules'] = array_diff_key($book['rules'], $except);
    }
    if (!empty($append))
        $book = array_merge_recursive($book, $append);

    return $book;
}
```

Then, in the controller that receives the request you can simply do:

```
$vb = User::ValidationBook();
$vb["rules"]["user.client_secret"] .= $request->input("user")["client_id"];
$data = $request->validate($vb["rules"], $vb["messages"]);
```

Notice that you could define each of the errors, and if something has more than one issues, the response will send all the rules that failed.